# using ravendb with asp.net identity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to use ravendb in my asp.net mvc5 application. I've found [this nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Identity.RavenDB/2.0.0-pre-06) package.

My question is: should I create new mvc application with auth (individual user accounts) and then remove entity framework and then install above nuget package for identity with ravendb or should I create empty mvc project and than install nuget package?

Comment: That's for you to decide, not us.

Comment: who's decide ? should I or should I? :)

Comment: maybe this can help: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/aspnet-identity-ravendb--fully-asynchronous-new-and-sweet-asp-net-identity-implementation-for-ravendb